# Issue with updating multiple values with the same key using HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

I'm having an issue where one key/value pair is getting updated properly, but the other values with the same key are not getting updated.  I'm using a HashMap which consists of a List of Strings (Item Nbr) as the key and the values stored as a List of Strings (PO Nbr), so it is essentially a one to many in that regard.  Below is the code I have for implementing this HashMap but I am just stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void process(List<PoBean> excelData,List<String> errors) throws CustomException 
{       
    Map<String,ArrayList<String>> poNbrItemNbrMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> poNbrList = new ArrayList<String>();

    int recordCount = excelData.size();

    for(PoBean bean : excelData)
    {                                       
        if(rowValidator.validate(bean, errors))
        {
            if (!newErrorInRow(errors)) 
            {
                poNbrList.add(bean.getPoId());
                poNbrItemNbrMap.put(bean.getItemNbr(),bean.getPoId());
            }           
        }
    }

    List<DutyFees> dutyFeesTempDAO = myService.getAssocIdByPOAndItemNbr(new ArrayList<String>(poNbrItemNbrMap.keySet()),new ArrayList<String>(poNbrItemNbrMap.values()));           

    for(DutyFees duty : dutyFeesTempDAO)
    {   
        Double dutyFees = new Double(0);
        if(poNbrItemNbrMap.containsKey(duty.getItemNbr()) && poNbrItemNbrMap.containsValue(duty.getPoId())) 
        {               
            for(PoBean dutyBean : excelData)
            {
                if(duty.getPoId().equals(dutyBean.getPoId()) && duty.getItemNbr().equals(dutyBean.getItemNbr()))
                {
                    dutyFees = new Double(dutyBean.getDutyFees());
                    break;
                }
            }
            Boolean result = myService.updateDutyFeesByAssocID(duty.getAssocId(), dutyFees);            
        }                               
    }       
}
```

Comment: "the other values with the same key are not getting updated" -- You can't have other values with the same key in a `HashMap`.

Comment: You need a `Map<String, List<String>>` if you have one-to-many relationships.

Comment: Or a `MultiMap` from some 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want one to many but your code has one to one

```
HashMap<String,String> poNbrItemNbrMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

One string key to one string value

The part in italics is in contrast with the part in bold from your question.

> *I'm using a HashMap which consists of a List of Strings (Item Nbr) as
>   the key and the values stored as a List of Strings (PO Nbr),* **so it is
>   essentially a one to many in that regard.**

Italics means many to many.
Bold means one to many.

Anyhow, Let me give you both implementation to play with.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("= One to Many =");
    Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap = new HashMap<>();
    String key = "list of 4 strings";
    List<String> valuesList = Arrays.asList("one","two","three","four");
    stringListMap.put(key,valuesList);
    stringListMap.forEach((strings, strings2) -> System.out.println(strings.toString() + strings2.toString()));

    System.out.println("= Many to Many =");
    Map<List<String>, List<String>> listListMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4");
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("one","two","three","four");
    listListMap.put(keys,values);
    listListMap.forEach((strings, strings2) -> System.out.println(strings.toString() + strings2.toString()));


  }
}
```

---

**EDIT** response to your comment. 
Not sure what you mean in that comment, but I do see couple of problems. First when you are putting in map you are putting what seems like a item number and po id, so they both seem to be of type single Strings and not ArrayList. So I am not even sure how are you able to compile that.  Unless your getPoId actually is getPoIds and returns a list.  I am talking about this line

```
poNbrItemNbrMap.put(bean.getItemNbr(),bean.getPoId());
```

Now regarding

```
new ArrayList<String>(poNbrItemNbrMap.values())
```

you can not initialize array list like that.

I don't know what is the signature of getAssocIdByPoAndItemNbr function is so can't suggest an answer. However, if all you want is to send the map values then send it directly why put it in a as a constructor argument to new ArrayList<>()?

Comment: I understand now what I was doing wrong, but now whenever I do this, it is asking me to change the return type of getPoId() in my bean class to List<String> so it won't work just doing that.  I'm unsure of how I would go about storing the values of that bean into a list.  Would I just do that in my iterator I have setup to go through the excelData?  I'm sort of lost and confused at this point.

Comment: `List` is an abstract type so you need to initialize the concrete implementation of a list, say `ArrayList` for example. So, you initialize it as `List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>;` This initializes a list of Strings. You can change the Generics to PoBean if you want to store /create a list of beans. 

Later you can add values to it by calling `listOfStrings.add("hello");`

Comment: So now I'm having an issue after using generics and <String, ArrayList<String>>).  I initialized an ArrayList<String> object and in my !newErrorsInRows(errors) check I am saying poNbrList.add(bean.getPOId());...now, where I have the code new ArrayList<String>(poNbrItemNbrMap.values() as an input parameter for getAssocIdByPOAndItemNbr, it is saying to change to ArrayList<String>, but that does nothing to take in all the entered values.  That method in my constants file states it expects (List<String>, List<String>).  I'm stuck

Comment: FYI I updated the code in the original post to reflect using Map<String, ArrayList<String>> and doing poNbrList.add(bean.getPoId()) inside the if (!newErrorsInRows(errors)) check

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the first part of your `process` is clear: convert a list of `PoBean` objects into a `Map<String, List<String>>`, grouping the objects by `itemNbr` into a list. Here's the code that does just that:

```
// One-to-many relationship requires the value to be a List
// Better not say ArrayList here because then you put unnecessary
// Restrictions on the code.
Map<String, List<String>> poNbrItemNbrMap = new HashMap<>();

for(PoBean bean : excelData)
{                                       
    if(rowValidator.validate(bean, errors))
    {
        if (!newErrorInRow(errors)) 
        {
            String key = bean.getItemNbr();
            List<String> value = poNbrItemNbrMap.get(key);
            if (value == null) {
                // This is first time we see this item nbr,
                // Create a new list to hold the values
                value = new ArrayList<>();
                poNbrItemNbrMap.put(key, value);
            }
            // Just add the value to the list
            value.add(bean.getPoId());
        }           
    }
}
```

Now the second part is confusing, especially this line:

```
List<DutyFees> dutyFeesTempDAO = myService.getAssocIdByPOAndItemNbr(new ArrayList<String>(poNbrItemNbrMap.keySet()),new ArrayList<String>(poNbrItemNbrMap.values()));
```

The first parameter barely makes sense, it's passing in the keys as `List`; That's okay. The second parameter doesn't compile because you need `new ArrayList<List<String>>(poNbrItemNbrMap.values())`. Yes, you need a list of lists of strings. But that's just the beginning. **By doing this, you basically removed the relationship between the keys and the values, the `getAssocIdByPOAndItemNbr` method could not associate the keys and their respective values any more. It cannot assume the first item in the keys maps to the first item in the values. which means anything we did in the first part is useless.**

Comment: So if I want to associate one key to a list of strings, and better yet a set of keys with a Collection of a List of Strings, how can that happen?  the getAssocIdByPOAndItemNbr method expects a List<String>,List<String>, I could change that to expect a Set<String> keySet, Collection<List<String>> values but would that also disable the ability to associate the keys to their respective values?

Comment: Why not just pass in the map we just created?